# Why is engaging in homosexual sex sinful?

Tags: sin, punishment, homosexuality

Why is it sinful in Islam to engage in sexual activity if one is a homosexual? Is this not a burden too great to bear? For example imagine a heterosexual person is forbidden from engaging in sexual activity, wouldn't that be denying a basic need of this person?

Edit - apparently a counterargument put forward to part of my question is that sexual desire is not to be considered a need. Fair enough I am willing to concede that for the sake for argument and say that yes sure, food is vital and therefore is a need and sexual desire does not fall under the same category.

My question is why is homosexuality considered sinful if it is naturally occurring? What about it makes it morally reprehensible?

Answer (score 3):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem
As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullah wa baraktuhu.
I ask allah the most generous to befriend us in this dunya and akhira and make us blessed wherever we are.
Have patience  reading this ive mentioned 5 points and an conclusion.

Saying what is halal or harram is  speaking on behalf of our creator and messenger muhammad صلى الله عليه و سلم 
Allah says
" And do not say, concerning the falsehood which your tongues utter, 'This is halal and that is haram,' in order to fabricate a lie against Allah; assuredly those who fabricate a lie against Allah will not prosper. (Surah nahl:116)

If we want to determine what is halal or harram we refer to quran sunnah upon understanding of companions and scholars whose words are based upon the aforementioned sources.

So what does the quran say about being homosexual.
1) That it is a sin which is punishable hence a major sin hence harram.
In surah 27vs54-58
We also sent Lot and recall when he told his people: "Do you commit shameless acts with your eyes open?Do you lustfully approach men instead of women? Nay, you engage in acts of sheer ignorance.But this had only one answer from his people. They said: "Expel Lot's folk from your city. They pretend to be absolutely clean."  Eventually We saved (Lot) and his family, except his wife. We had decreed that she should be among those who would remain behind.And We rained down upon them a rain. It was an evil rain for those who had already been warned

2)also in the ahadith the prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم said
Ibn ‘Abbaas said: “The Messenger of Allaah said: “Allaah will not look at a man who has intercourse with his wife in her anus.” (Narrated by Ibn Abi Shaybah, 3/529).

So if this is for a wife whom allah made halal what about homosexual acts with someone your not married to and are forbidden to ever be married to.

3) my brother you mentioned that what if it is too much for a person to bear?
Akhi lusts are one of the hardest things to overcome and we ask allah to protect us all.
But we can cure these lusts by remedies allah has stipulated for us in the quran sunnah way of compainons advice from scholars.
Difference between a person controlling himself who is heterosexual and person having to control themselves who is homosexual is allah made hetrosexuality halal and disliked to not get married and because this benefits the person and society and brings children etc.
But homosexuality allah has made harram because this harms the person and society and stops the growth of the nation and spreads diseases etc.

4) you mentioned what if it is too much to bear? Lusts are never too great to bear its only in the mind and whispers of shaytan which make us feel like that sometimes torture etc are things which are too much to bear sometimes.
Because ask yourself if you were given a billion pound by the government and they said we will keep you on observation and if you go back to homosexual acts we will take it away.
Or you knew your mum or most beloved to you would die if you done these acts most likely you wouldn't do it.
Because a person leaves something he loves for that which he loves more so love allah the most and anything disliked by allah you will leave.
Conclusion:
In surah hadid vs 14 theres a conversation between the people of paradise and those who will go hellfire
Allah says 
"The hypocrites will call to the believers, "Were we not with you?" They will say, "Yes, but you put yourselves in trails and tribulations and awaited and doubted, and wishful thinking deluded you until there came the command of Allah . And the Deceiver deceived you concerning Allah .

‌An imam once said to us about the statement "but you put yourselves in trails and tribulations" this means do not put yourself in situations you will have to sin. So it is best for a person to hide in the mountain away from everyone safeguarding his religion than if he fears for himself.
, where he narrated that Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Soon there will come a time when the best wealth a Muslim will have will be sheep which he will take to the mountaintops and places where rain falls, fleeing for the sake of his religious commitment from tribulation
In bukhari chapter of fitan

Conclusion..
No person who practices homosexual acts should make it halal or make excuses for it or tell other people your free to do it or abandon his or her five daily prayers and give up worshipping allah alone.
Because if leave salah, making what allah said is harram harram halal halal and their tawheed.
Even if they were hetrosexual they would enter the fire.

And allah knows best.

‌

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points. If the relevant posts are unclear to the point that you need extensive discussion to explain how it answers the question, chances are the post needs to be edited.

Comment: @Abu haneef Musa " But homosexuality allah has made harram because this harms the person and society and stops the growth of the nation and spreads diseases etc." Please explain how this is the case.